# Construct a class from a function using a parameter's name (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to construct a class from a function using one of the function's parameters: `id`, but the code thinks I'm trying to set the parameter as the class. This is my code:

```js
function assureVote() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit your vote?")) {
        submitVote();
    }
}
function submitVote(id = document.getElementById("id"), party = document.getElementById("party")) {
    const id = new SubmittedVote(party.value);
}
class SubmittedVote {
    constructor(party) {
        this._party = party;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="id" autocomplete="off" type="password">
        <select name="Party" id="party">
            <option value="mr">Melon Republic</option>
            <option value="dd">DD2021</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="assureVote()">Submit vote</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that in the `submitVote` function, I have `const id = new SubmittedVote(party.value);`, and JavaScript thinks that I'm trying to declare the `id` parameter as the class, which returns an error because I used `const`.
If you have a solution, please post it. Thanks.

Comment: Why not something like `const vote = new SubmittedVote(party.value);` instead? Why even use `id` again? If there's a point to that I don't see, just remove the `const`. Also, why even have those parameters in the submitVote function?

Comment: Your error is because your redefining the variable `id`, you use id as the parameter to your function.

Comment: submitVote vote has parameter id and in that function, you are declaring that again. that's not allowed in javascript except var

Comment: @ChrisG I want to construct a new class for every `id` parameter that is entered, and for that class to be declared as the `id` parameter. I also want that class to have a `_party` attribute that is the same as the `party` parameter.

Comment: With regards to the terminology you're creating instances of a class, not new classes. Still, that doesn't change the fact that you're trying to redeclare the already existing `id` as a constant, which is not allowed. Also, again, your code doesn't make much sense to me. You have two params with default values but you're never providing any arguments when you call `submitVote`. And why do you want the new instance of the SubmittedVote class to also be named `id`? Also, why have that vote instance in the first place when you're not using it?

Comment: Here's my version: https://jsfiddle.net/ra29ubc0/

Comment: @ChrisG Your version works, so thanks for sharing it. It's not exactly what I wanted but it'll do the trick. With regards to your other comment, I wanted the class instance to have the same name as the `id` so I can know who voted for what. I'll use your version in my code. Again, thank you for sharing it. Also, can you post an answer with that code so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: `I wanted the class instance to have the same name as the id so I can know who voted for what` That sentence does not make any sense. You are declaring a const and then immediately discarding it (by ending the function without doing anything with the local `const`). Even if naming it `id` helped *anything* with "know[ing] who voted for what" (it doesn't, at *all*), you still have to store the created vote instance somewhere, or it'll disappear. Thanks for saying that my code "will do the trick", given how fundamentally broken yours is.